# LESSCSS - use calculation and return value

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

H i,

Hoping you can help.

Is there a way for **LESS** to return just a value - *feel like I'm missing something very obvious*

Say I have:

```
@unit:em;
@basevalue:1;
```

Can I use something to give me a shorthand return for -

```
.someClass {  padding: ~'@{basevalue}@{unit}'; }
```

*Like say:*

```
.returnUnit() { ~'@{basevalue}@{unit}'; }

.someClass {  padding: returnUnit(); }
```

**because what I'm ultimately hoping for is:**

```
.returnUnit(@val) { @basevalue*@val@{unit}; }
.someClass {  padding:returnUnit(0.5); }
```

---

Using a mixing I have to define the style property, however the value of this *return function* would be used for many different css properties.

---

Hope I made sense and I am just lacking deeper rtfm.

Many Thanks if you can.

---

**Update** as @Chococrocs [pointer to the docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature), thanks.

```
.average(@x, @y) {
  @average: ((@x + @y) / 2);
}

div {
  .average(16px, 50px); // "call" the mixin
  padding: @average;    // use its "return" value
}
```

- Looks like what I need ? - *just seeing if I can always tag on the unit variable to it....*

  ---

### Update: That gets part way ...

```
.unitRelative(@val) {
  @value : @basevalue*@val;
  @relative: ~'@{value}@{unit}';
}
/* usage */

 .someClass { 
  .unitRelative(2);
  padding: @relative;
}
```

But not when

```
.someClass {
    .unitRelative(2);
    padding:@relative;
    .unitRelative(3);
    margin:@relative;
}
```

Is there another way ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to separate `@unit` and `@basevalue` in LESS.  Does it hurt your design to combine them into a single variable?  It doesn't seem like you'd lose much by doing that, since any time you change one, you'd need to change the other as well.

Comment: Thanks @recursive. You could be right, can I still multiple say like - `10em * 6` ? - Ive just added an edit too with what looks like the right lines - just trying that now

Comment: I have been combining them like `padding:~'@{baseval}@{unit}'; but it would be neater to be more Dry

Comment: Personally I would suggest one of [these two methods](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/2e51755b5d29005c13ed) (the rest looks extremely bloating for me).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

LESS has no way as of yet to create a true "function," so we cope with it.

### First

You can just [use the unit function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-unit), like so:

**LESS**

```
.someClass {  padding: unit(@basevalue, @unit); }
.someOtherClass {  padding: unit(@basevalue*0.5, @unit); }
```

**CSS**

```
.someClass {
  padding: 1em;
}
.someOtherClass {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

### Second

The [mixins as functions](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature) is okay in some situations, but as you discovered, has the limitation of *only setting the value once* on the first call (and that is assuming a variable of the same name does not exist in that scope already).

**LESS (first works right, second doesn't)**

```
.returnUnit(@val:1) { 
    @return: unit(@basevalue*@val, @unit); 
}

.someThirdClass { 
  .returnUnit(0.4); 
  padding: @return;
 }
.someOoopsClass { 
  .returnUnit(0.4); 
  padding: @return; 
  .returnUnit(0.3); 
  margin: @return;
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.someThirdClass {
  padding: 0.4em;
}
.someOoopsClass {
  padding: 0.4em;
  margin: 0.4em; /* Ooops! Not 0.3em! */
}
```

### Third

Limitation of the Second idea can be avoided by a second wrapping, as it isolates the scope for each variable returned by `.returnUnit()`, like so:

**LESS**

```
.someAccurateClass { 
    & {
        .returnUnit(0.4); 
        padding: @return;
    } 
    & { 
        .returnUnit(0.3); 
        margin: @return;
    }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.someAccurateClass {
  padding: 0.4em;
  margin: 0.3em; /* Yes! */
}
```

### Fourth

It may be better to merge ideas from the First and Third by adding some global variables and doing this:

**LESS**

```
@unit:em;
@basevalue:1;
@val: 1;
@setUnit: unit(@basevalue*@val, @unit);

.someAwesomeClass { 
    & {
        @val: .2; 
        padding: @setUnit;
    } 
    & {
        @val: .1; 
        margin: @setUnit;
    }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.someAwesomeClass {
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0.1em;
}
```

So here we are using the `unit` function still as the First idea, but have assigned it to the variable `@setUnit`, so each time the variable is called, it runs the function. We still isolate our property blocks using the `& {}` syntax like in the Third solution, but now we just set the `@val` to what we want and call the `@setUnit` where we want.

Comment: that fourth one is ace! Sweet, thanks for the in depth explanation, just what I was looking for. Nice use of the `@val` scoping it up like that. It bends my head how Less uses variables this way :) thanks.

Comment: Goddammit, because of that i just lost over 1 hour at work -.- They really should but the information about "unit" to the polarising section. Even better, they should it add to their feature list first!

Answer (score 6):

There is a hack that is mentioned [here](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/637) by fabienevain using a global js function.  Seems to be good option if you want a function with actual return value.

```
@fn: ~`fn = function(a) { return a; }`;

@arg: 8px;

p {
    font-size: ~`fn("@{arg}")`;
}
```

Comment: ace! Will try that , +1 thanks - ) I've added the code from that link to your answer )

Answer (score 3):

I think you look for this, Mixin as a function

http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature

Reading your question, I think is what you're wishing, ;D

Comment: Thanks @Chococroc I was reading that page before, added it to the q and having a play ..

Answer (score 1):

```
// mixin
.parseInt(@string) {
    @parseInt: unit(@string, );
}
```

Usage:

```
.selector {
    .parseInt(100px);
    width: @parseInt + 10; // px will automatically be appended
}
```

Result:

```
.selector {
    width: 110px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the simplest work around would be to pass the property and the value.

**mixin.less**

```
.lighter(@property, @color) {
  @{property}: multiply(white, fade(@color, 10%));
}
```

**use.less**

```
.my-class{
  .lighter(background-color, #FF0000);
}
```

Results:

```
.my-class{
  background-color: #fbe8eb;
}
```